# Header-based authentication for REST API in Phoenix

Tags: rest, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm implementing a rest api in Elixir. An api-key is passed to each request to authenticate a user. In a plug I have this:

```
defmodule MyApp.ApiSecurity do
  def init(options) do
    options
  end

 def call(conn, _opts) do
    # checking if "api-key" headers exists
    # and key is valid

    # .... what's next?
    # if it's a) valid
    # b) invalid or there's no "api-key" header
    # ???
 end
end
```

I know how to implement it for a normal, form-based authentication with a state and session. But in rest api there's no session. Then, what should I do? In other words, What should be in the rest of the function "call" when a) an api-key is valid b) invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the key is invalid or not present, you'd normally send the error message with a proper error status code and then call `Plug.Conn.halt/1`, which will stop this request from going further through the plug pipeline. If they key is valid, you'd probably want to assign some value to the `conn`, (e.g. `user_id`) which the rest of your application can use.

For example:

```
def call(conn, _opts) do
  case authenticate(conn) do
    {:ok, user_id} ->
      conn
      |> assign(:user_id, user_id)
    :error ->
      conn
      |> send_resp(401, "Unauthenticated")
      |> halt()
    end
  end
end
```

Now, any plugs that are plugged after this one can be sure that there exists a valid `user_id` in `conn.assigns` and can make use of it.

For a more real-world approach, you can see how `guardian` does this:

- [Guardian.Plug.EnsureResource](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/blob/fa041f08c6a241b2707dae77c504e7e5c1b411e0/lib/guardian/plug/ensure_resource.ex)
- [Guardian.Plug.ErrorHandler](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/blob/fa041f08c6a241b2707dae77c504e7e5c1b411e0/lib/guardian/plug/error_handler.ex)

Comment: yes, but `|> assign(:user_id, user_id)` inserts it into a session. therefore, it creates a state. where in rest api there shouldn't be a state, right?

Comment: `assign` doesn't insert into a session (that's `put_session`). `assign` will only insert the value to the in memory `conn` and any value there will be deleted forever as soon as `conn` is garbage collected (usually just after the response is sent to the client).

Comment: ok. then how would I access that stored value from a controller?

Comment: `conn.assigns.user_id`